# Can Google detect or track analytics of a website opened in iframe?

Tags: google-analytics, web-deployment

I think the title already described the problem. But the purpose of doing is putting a back button to the previous site and I think putting it in an iframe and without leaving the current domain is the only way to do it.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "can GA track an iframe without trackingcode by default" (no), or "can I do something that GA will track an iFrame without tracking code" (in which case irimawis answer seems relevant).

Comment: Of course it has tracking code, i'm just asking if it tracks the same if the site is opened from an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a first party iFrame (which I understand is the case) Google analytics should be able to send the data back as long as you use

```
window.parent._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', eventCategory, eventAtion, eventLabel]);
```

You also may want to override the onclick event preventDefaultBehavior(); so that your script is able to be sent before actually the click goes to the previous link

Comment: The problem is I dont have access or control to the website inside the iframe, i'm basically talking about the pageview event for analytics on the website inside the iframe, does it get track?

Comment: Yes it does, The content of the iFrame is a full HTML page with it's scripts and content running

Comment: @irimawi, are you sure that (first party) iframes get tracked? I think the only way to track iframed content and engagement is if you have the GA tracking code in there as well, first party or not.

Comment: @nyuen For first party iframe, you are able to inject script/code/nodes without a problem, select CSS path for the iframe and use contentWindow.document then you are in business where you can inject things. 3rd party iframe is not something you can access from the main frame, hence it is a blackbox.

Comment: @nyuen Yes the tracking code is there I'm just asking if it works the same when inside an iframe or if it works at all.